# Redirect to another webpage using data from a form in jQuery and Node.JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect

I have a main website with a form and a search bar, and I `POST` the content of the search bar to another webpage using Javascript.

Node.JS (using Express) routing code -

```
app.get('/', function(req,res) {
  res.render("index");
});

app.get('/dashboard/', function(req,res) {
  res.render("dashboard");
});
```

Javascript code for direction to `dashboard` -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#searchButton").click(function() {
        var values = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url: "dashboard",
            type: "POST",
            data: values
        });
    });
});
```

I know using AJAX is wrong because I'm loading a new page, but doing something like

```
$.post( '/dashboard', { 'foo' : 'bar' }, function() {
    window.location.href = '/dashboard';
});
```

loses the POST data. What is an efficient way to resolve this?

Comment: Why not just post the form the usual way? It really doesn't make any sense posting it with ajax if you are going to navigate away to that same page anyway.

Comment: Don't use `.ajax`, just let the form submit as usual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing doesn't seem to make any sense at all to me.... Why not just

```
<form method="POST" action="/dashboard">
</form>
```

And skip the AJAX entirely?